# In chefspec is it possible to write a method once and call that method in other spec files?

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

I am trying to write a method `test_run(first_param,second_param)` in one spec file `program_spec.rb` and I want to call this method `test_run` in another spec file `second_program_spec.rb`. How do I call the method which is declared in `program_spec.rb` to be used in another spec file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a helper_spec.rb and include it in the required specfiles.
I attach a link to the documentation examples.

[https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module#include-a-module-in-only-some- example-groups](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module#include-a-module-in-only-some-%20example-groups)

Best Regards.